# Drupal: Add Archive to Primary Links as SubNav

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view, drupal-views

My site has news articles that I want to add to the sub-nav under "News" as years.

News

- 2010
- 2009

But I only want the current year and 1 previous year. And I need it to happen automatically.

I know how to create a page view that will only show news articles from the previous year, I just don't know how to change the Menu & Node Title to the archived year.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a custom views block display that prints out you menu as desired?

Comment: Well the thing is that I want to put the menu inside another menu (say Primary Links->News->Dynamic Archive Links)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, got it.
You might try the Views Build Menu module http://drupal.org/project/views_build_menu
It seems to add a menu display called "menu" which allows you to set a parent menu item under which you views-generated menu should appear.
Here's the documentation (with interesting screenshots) for Views Build Menu: http://drupal.org/node/831564